# Object has no method findOne, after Insert hook

Tags: meteor, hook

This is curious.

I created a hook to update some data of related collections after an update. The code is like this:

```
@Votes.after.insert (userId, doc) ->
  person = People.findOne name: doc.candidate
  person.votes += 1
```

When I insert a new Vote everything works fine: the hook is called and the votes are updated just fine. However I got this on the server log:

```
Exception while invoking method '/votes/insert' TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'findOne'
```

and this on the console of the browser:

```
errorClass {error: 500, reason: "Internal server error", details: undefined, message: "Internal server error [500]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"}
```

I didn't understand why I got those errors if everything worked fine.

Comment: Is the `People` collection defined somewhere? Is it defined in a `lib` folder, so it's available both on the client and server?

Comment: Yes to both. My models files are in lib folder and People is defined as: `@People = new Mongo.Collection("people")` in file people.coffee while the code above is in vote.coffe in the same folder